# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: learning_logs\base.html

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm following along a project from the Python crash course book. I'm supposed to be deploying the webapp to heroku but I keep receiving a Server Error 505 warning.

The problem:

---

I have tried to do various things with my `setings.py` file, but none appear to work.

`SETTINGS.PY`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [r'\learning_logs\templates\learning_logs',
                 r'\users\templates\users',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    }, ]
```

Project setup:

```
learning_log:   11_env   learning_log:
     .git
     learning_log:
       ....
     learning_logs:
       templates:
         learning_logs:
           *all html files including base.html*
     ...
```

If anyone requires more information to answer the question, please let
me know.

Comment: Your question doesn't exist, "it just doesn't work" is not a question. In order for it not to be closed, please provide the information necessary, after having read [ask] and its associated links.

Comment: sorry about that, first time asking a question on stack. perhaps the detail i added is better?